# Trouble with editing code ( Recalling the wrong sheet ) - Error ( Run - time error '1004' ) Invalid Parameter

Tags: excel, vba

This code was found from

I attempted to edit it by having the table in one table and the graph in another sheet.

Original:

```
Sub PieMarkers()

Dim chtMarker As Chart
Dim chtMain As Chart
Dim intPoint As Integer
Dim rngRow As Range
Dim lngPointIndex As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set chtMarker = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(“chtMarker”).Chart
Set chtMain = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(“chtMain”).Chart

Set rngRow = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names(“PieChartValues”).RefersTo)

For Each rngRow In Range(“PieChartValues”).Rows

chtMarker.SeriesCollection(1).Values = rngRow
chtMarker.Parent.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
lngPointIndex = lngPointIndex + 1
chtMain.SeriesCollection(1).Points(lngPointIndex).Paste

Next

lngPointIndex = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

My Edit was to add a

```
 Dim wk As Worksheet
```

Followed by

```
Set wk = Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

Where the graph will be ( in sheet1 )

Followed by

```
Set chtMain = wk.ChartObjects("chtMain").Chart
```

This line of code is the problem

```
chtMarker.SeriesCollection(1).Values = rngRow
```

Comment: Note that the fancy quotes you use `“ ”` are not allowed in VBA. You must change them in your code to the straight ones `" "`. Replace them.

Comment: @TimStack It has been edited. It was an error on my part

Comment: This `Set rngRow = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names(“PieChartValues”).RefersTo)` seems to be unnecessary as well, since you are using `rngRow` as a variable in a `For Each` loop later on..

Comment: Also charted `Sheets` cannot be accessed via the `Worksheet` object, but should be via the `Sheets` instead => `Set wk = Sheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: @StavrosJon I did what you suggested and found that the error still exists with the same problem

Comment: @Rawrplus Sadly it wasn't successful.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to everyone who has helped.

I have attached a solution that was built by the assistance of everyone. Cheers

```
Sub PieMarkers()

    Dim chtMarker As Chart
    Dim chtMain As Chart
    Dim intPoint As Integer
    Dim rngRow As Range
    Dim lngPointIndex As Long
    Dim wk As Worksheet

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wk = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set chtMarker = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chtMarker").Chart
    Set chtMain = wk.ChartObjects("chtMain").Chart

    Set chtMain = wk.ChartObjects("chtMain").Chart
    Set rngRow = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names("PieChartValues").RefersTo)

    For Each rngRow In Range("PieChartValues").Rows
        chtMarker.SeriesCollection(1).Values = rngRow
        chtMarker.Parent.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
        lngPointIndex = lngPointIndex + 1
        chtMain.SeriesCollection(1).Points(lngPointIndex).Paste
    Next

    lngPointIndex = 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that you still have this line twice `Set chtMain = wk.ChartObjects("chtMain").Chart` remove one of them. Also remove `Set rngRow = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names("PieChartValues").RefersTo)` as it not needed, because you set `rngRow` in your `For Each` loop already.